# URxvt.font ignoring font size

Tags: x-resources, xrdb

I have tried any and all combinations of the `URxvt.font` but it just isn't working. This is how my `.Xresources` file looks like:

```
! URxvt
URxvt.foreground: white
URxvt.font: xft:monospace:size=10.5
URxvt.letterSpace: -1
URxvt.depth: 32
URxvt.background: [90]#000000
URxvt.scrollBar: false
! Xft
Xft.autohint: 0
Xft.lcdfilter: lcddefault
Xft.hintstyle: hintslight
Xft.hinting: 1
Xft.antialias: 1
Xft.rgba: rgb
Xft.dpi: 120
```

However it doesn't care if I set `size` to `10.5` or `100.5`, the size won't change. Even `xrdb -query` shows it's set to `size=100.5` but all the text would be very small. It only happens with the `monospace` font (which is mapped to Inconsolata). Any other font gets resized just fine. `pixelsize` works, too, but I need to use `size` because it lets the font scale according to `Xft.dpi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after a very intensive session of trial and error I discovered that fontconfig actually overrides `Xresources`, and since I had set size to `<int>10</int>` in my `font.conf` file, it was overriding the size I set with `Xresources`.